# Threshold row for mysql selection with PK varchar(30)

Tags: mysql

Need to find the minimum threshold in mysql. I mean to say I have around 1 million rows of data in a mysql table with primary keys of type varchar(30). Now for selection, I need all selections to be made above 1000th row, which means the cursor must never point below 1000th row in the table. If primary keys were INT, there were no problem but I need the result of the following query with PK as varchar.

Following query returns the first row after 1000th row when the PK (here, sec_packing_id) is INT.

```
SELECT sec_packing_id FROM secondary_packing WHERE MIN(sec_packing_id) > 1000 ORDER BY sec_packing_id ASC LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Comment: try this : cast(sec_packing_id as int)

Comment: I had already tried to use the cast function, but no luck :(. I also tried to compare the ASCII value of the PKs but no it compares only the first character of the PK...
Thanks anyway... :)

Comment: try : convert(int, sec_packing_id) > 1000

Comment: Thanks, but both convert() and cast had been unsuccessful in getting my requirements... Finally I could manage to get the desired result by creating a dynamic view in which only a range of rows are selected whose MIN(PK) would be the lower threshold that I would need to get... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
declare @x TABLE (a varchar(30))
insert into @x values ('1123'),('2456'),('3458')
select * from @x where cast(a as int) >  2000
```

It's working very fine for me